# Слово «кашкорсе» какого рода?

Tags: грамматика, существительные, род

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой род у слова **кашкорсе**: мужской или средний?
Это несклоняемое существительное иноязычного происхождения и должно быть среднего рода. Но возможно, что оно относится к исключениям, и тогда род определяется по родовому понятию— трикотаж. Спасибо.